# how to change all the images on my site

Tags: javascript, html

How do companies with thousands of images on their sites update all the images and descriptions

I have tried using `getElementById();` and `document.write()`.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? A company with thousands of images hopefully uses a proper content management system to deal with this. The image paths and descriptions would be loaded from a database…

Comment: They use a CMS. What you wrote doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Pepe I think the OP uses Javascript on the client side to change the `src` attribute of all `img` tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157937/need-to-use-getelementbyid-many-times-to-change-image-src

Comment: or better again whats the easiest cms to set up

Comment: There's no single answer to this. It entirely depends on your business needs. The most popular CMS these days are WordPress, Drupal and Joomla! (this one's horrible though).

Answer (score 2):

Please **stop** doing what you're doing. If the real problem is that you have a website where image paths and descriptions are hardcoded into the pages, and you need to change them, then please change the source of the HTML/PHP/whatever files. Do it with a search and replace tool, if you must.

You really should have put the image paths and descriptions into a database and just referenced them whever you need them.

**Do not use JavaScript** to change how the website looks *after* it's been sent to the user. JavaScript only works in the client's browser. The images aren't changed persistently. The client will probably see the right image after the JavaScript code has run, but your page would *still* be broken. (Also to search engines, users without JavaScript, etc.)